# How do I get the text data called "DATA I WANT TO GRAB" in python?

Tags: python, json

How do I get "*DATA I WANT TO GRAB*" in python? I believe this is json.

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "DATA I WANT TO GRAB"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1630233665,
  "id": "cmpl-3cCXJCSRkiA5AQbjYkxZJYMgPjHqG",
  "model": "davinci:2020-05-03",
  "object": "text_completion"
}
```

Comment: `data['choices'][0]['text']`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
dct = {
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "DATA I WANT TO GRAB"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1630233665,
  "id": "cmpl-3cCXJCSRkiA5AQbjYkxZJYMgPjHqG",
  "model": "davinci:2020-05-03",
  "object": "text_completion"
}
print(dct['choices'][0]['text'])
```